# How to bind Background to the StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am developing Windows8 store app.I have Grid which is populating dynamically

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,16,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <GridView x:Name="chapterlist" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" ItemClick="onChapterClick" Padding="0" Height="600" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Width="260" Height="80" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=alreadyDownload, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">                                    
                                <TextBlock x:Name ="AAA" Text="{Binding Path=Chapter}" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="White" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=alreadyDownload}" Foreground="#073363" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,18,2,2" FontSize="10" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
            </Grid>
```

So i have to change the background color of StackPanel according to TextBlock value like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=alreadyDownload}" Foreground="#073363" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,18,2,2" FontSize="10" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

I have used ColorConverter like

```
class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, String culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.Equals("Already Downloaded "))
                return Colors.Red;
            else
                return Colors.White;
        }

        return Colors.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But my grid is not reflecting background color(infact no color at all,its transparent).Why it is happening? How can I solve this problem? Please help.I am attaching image for reference. Thanks in advance
[image]

So what I want is to show Grid with text Already Downloaded should be having some other color and rest of the Grids with different color.

Comment: just guessing: don't you need to set the binding mode to TwoWay-Binding? `{Binding Path=alreadyDownload,Mode=TwoWay}` Have you tried to set the background to any value? e.g. #0F0, to check if there is a binding or xaml markup problem?

Comment: It is TwoWay-Binding if its not set, isn't it?

Comment: @Lucas according to this [blog post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/xaml-binding-basics-101.html) not.

Comment: @Jan Hommes Curious. I use many input fields without give them a BindingMode and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @Lucas you are right, the default mode depends on the xaml-element. TextBoxes seem to have always a twoway binding. see this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx)

Comment: @JanHommes: yes I have used Background="#2D8AEF" and its working properly,but this 'll applicable to all grid items and I wants some item to be having other color

Comment: I declared  <UserControl.Resources><local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>, so is it because of this the problem came? or anything wrong in  <StackPanel Width="260" Height="80" Background="{Binding Path=alreadyDownload, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do the above mentioned scenerio

1)We can add Background property to the objects that populates ObservableCollection and using binding in xaml

```
<Grid Width="200" Background="{Binding Background}" />
```

This way we can choose every item color in the grid and change it dynamically just changing object property. Here Background property must be a string assigned with a valid color like

```
object.Background = "White"
```

2)Using Converter(as I used) to convert some existing property in your object to a color(refer my Converter class). We can also bind using some property like I used here

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=alreadyDownload}"
```

which'll look like

```
<StackPanel Width="260" Height="80" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=alreadyDownload, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">                                    
                            <TextBlock x:Name ="AAA" Text="{Binding Path=Chapter}" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="White" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=alreadyDownload}" Foreground="#073363" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,18,2,2" FontSize="10" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
```

So why my code is not running? Its because the IValueConverter returns object which should be a string, so instead of using

```
if (value.Equals("Already Downloaded "))
            return Colors.Red;
        else
            return Colors.White;
```

use

```
 if (value.Equals("Already Downloaded "))
                return "#FF0000";
            else
                return "#FFFFFF";
```

So its running perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value.Equals("Already Downloaded "))
```

Is it maybe the space between *Downloaded* and " ?

Comment: No I purposefully put blank space after because the value I am setting/getting is like that

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
if (value.Equals("Already Downloaded "))
        return Brushes.Red;
    else
        return Brushes.White;
```

Or If you want to use colors class you can use in this way.

```
new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
```

Hope this may be solve your issue.

Comment: It drops the options for customizing the colors, hence not recommended.

Comment: But the stackpanel wont accepts colors class. Just try to give it in code behind file you can understand what is the problem with Colors class